# How to make user managed transaction in jBoss

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jboss, transactions

I'm using *JBossV5* as my application server. It provides the connection for *mysql* and I'm using *jdbc* in my application. I want to manually commit transaction. I know it is not possible to use `autoCommit()`, `commit()` or `rollback()` in `Connection` class since it is a container managed transaction. So, I set the property to make `autoCommit` `false` in the *mysql-ds.xml* configuration file. But I can't still do the transaction manually, whenever `commit`/`rollback` is called, it makes error. Can anybody tell me how I can do the transaction maually calling the commit method in the connection class?.

My mysql-ds.xml file is as follows

```
<datasources> 
   <xa-datasource>

      <jndi-name>DB</jndi-name>

      <xa-datasource-property name="URL">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample_db</xa-datasource-property>
      <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
      <xa-datasource-property name="User">root</xa-datasource-property>
      <xa-datasource-property name="Password"></xa-datasource-property>
      <connection-property name="autoCommit">false</connection-property>      

   </xa-datasource>  
</datasources>
```

Comment: @ Gabriel Aramburu yes

Comment: Probably what you need is define the ejb transaction type as Bean Managed Transaction. [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0415__EJB3/BeanManagedTransaction.htm) there's an example.